# Create server side text from wordpress page

Tags: php

I would like to store a wordpress page as text on the server for access in a custom application. Specifically I want a div of class '.entry-content' on a page url like below

http://www.example.com/dataFeed/
or 
http://www.example.com/wordpress/?p=7914

I've tried a get_post() call in php like below but recieve a response of "Reload the page to get source"

```
<?php require_once("./wp-blog-header.php"); ?>
<?php
$post_id = 7914;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
echo $queried_post;
?>
```

Is there any way I could either of the tasks below?

• Force Wordpress to create an html version of the above page
• Create a text dump of the page that resides on the server

Answer (score 0):

One issue with your original code is that the returned `$queried_post` is a php object, which can't be output in whole with a simple `echo`. If you tried to echo a property of the object, like `echo $queried_post->post_title;` that might work.

That said, I'd handle this with a rewrite endpoint to keep things self-contained. The below code adds the endpoint `data-feed`, which when visited will output the title of the post as text/plain.

```
function wpd_rewrite_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'data-feed', EP_ROOT );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_rewrite_endpoint' );

function wpd_parse_query( $wp ){
    if( array_key_exists( 'data-feed', $wp->query_vars ) ) {
        $post_id = 7914;
        $queried_post = get_post( $post_id );
        header( "Content-Type: text/plain" );
        echo $queried_post->post_title;
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpd_parse_query' );
```

Comment: I am assuming this should be added to the wp-includes/functions.php file? What will trigger it to create the 'data-feed' endpoint?

Comment: it should be added in a plugin, or a theme's `functions.php` file. nothing in `wp-includes` should ever be modified. I'm not sure what you mean by "what will trigger it". it registers the endpoint on `init`, so you can visit `whatever.com/data-feed/` and the corresponding `wpd_parse_query` function will run on those requests. just note that you will need to flush rewrite rules for it to take effect, either by visiting the permalinks settings page, or [adding a function to flush rules on plugin activation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules#Examples).